# How to get Selected Text from WebBrowser WPF Control and bind it to a string object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, web, browser

Here is my web browser:

```
<WebBrowser viewmodel:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding SelectedNode.ContentData.FileName, Converter={StaticResource converter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

In fact, text in my WebBrowser Control can be Selected.

I wonder if I can retrieve the Selected portion in a string object?

PS: When right-clicking the Selected portion , I'd noticed that user can copy selected text. So my second question will be "Can we get the copied text?" I mean the copied portion should be saved somewhere in some environment variable, can we get it in c#?

Comment: Copied content is available from `Clipboard`.

Comment: @YoussefMessaoudi you cannot bind selection text but you can get it manually

Comment: @dkozl : how can I get selection manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind selected text from `WebBrowser` but you can get it manually like so:

```
var doc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
if (doc != null)
{
    var currentSelection = doc.selection;
    if (currentSelection != null)
    {
        var selectionRange = currentSelection.createRange();
        if (selectionRange != null)
        {
            var selectionText = selectionRange.Text;
            //do something with selected text
        }
    }
}
```

where `webBroswer` is your browser control

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBroswer" ... />
```

but you'll need to add reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` and to answer your second question you can get copied text from clipboard with [`Clipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
var copiedText = Clipboard.GetText();
```

Comment: the first answer about getting SelectionText worked well for me ! My question now for you is "how to do that without Code Behind"

Comment: You cannot bind to selection, you have no properties to bind to. You'll need to do it code behind

Comment: How can I get the start and end posion of `selectionText` ?

Comment: You don't get this information. Basically `currentSelection.createRange()` gives you [`IHTMLTxtRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741548(v=vs.85).aspx) which is also [`IHTMLTextRangeMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741561(v=vs.85).aspx), so you can do `var rangeMetrics = (mshtml.IHTMLTextRangeMetrics)selectionRange;` but none of these interfaces gives you selection start. `IHTMLTextRangeMetrics` gives you rectangle coordinates and that's as close as you'll get. If you want `IHTMLTxtRange` give you also `htmlText` property instead of just text.